# Java Iterating over HQL result with multiple tables

Tags: java, hibernate, iterator, hql, criteria

Say, using hql, I am selecting from four tables **(t1, t2, t3, t4)**.

This is how my hql would look like:

```
String multiTableHql = "from tbl1, tbl2, tbl3, tbl4"; // omitting  filtering
Query mtq = myDao.getInstance().getSession().createQuery(multiTableHql);
```

Now, my understanding is, calling **mtq.list()** would obviously bring a list of objects where the properties of each object would be those tables.

How would I iterate over that list, so that I can get each table individually?

I've tried **Iterator, ArrayList** with apparently no success. May be I'm doing it wrong.

Please suggest me a correct way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This query of yours is actually a Cartesian product. So if all tables have 1000 rows you will get 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 = 1 trillion results.

If we are talking about ToOne associations you are better off joining them with SQL or with HQL (if you have a navigable mapping from t1 to t2 to t3 to t4).

If those are ToMany associations, joining you will get a Cartesian product, which in this case, 4 distinct selects would get you 4 * 1000 results (better than 1 trillion).

Comment: actually, i'm doing many filtering with those selection, and my result is merely 15 tuples. I'm trying to find a way to iterate over that cartesian product and single out the tables.